# 〜か知らない or 〜か不安だ

Tags: grammar, words, questions, particle-か

I came across the following sentence in an exercise:

> インターネットで注文したセーターは、実際に着てみるまでサイズが_____が、ちょうどよかった。

Although only B and D make sense to me, here are the four propositions:

> A. 合わなかった
>
> B. 合うかどうか知らなかった
>
> C. 合わないかもしれない
>
> D. 合うか不安だった

I picked B, but the solution was D.
In both cases, I'd say the meaning is along the lines of `until I actually wore it, I wasn't sure if it was going to fit`.
My reasoning was that while both B and D are semantically correct, `不安だ` is rather strong, like I'm not gonna be anxious because I'm not sure if my sweater will fit.

Do you agree with the solution, that `サイズが合うか不安だった` is the correct answer?
If so, is B correct as well, or does it make sense at all?
Or am I right to think that `不安` adds a nuance that's too strong for this context?

Additionnally, I'm perplexed by `インターネットで注文したセーター`.
Is it alright to use `注文する` when shopping online?
I'm much more used to hearing and saying `注文` in the context of a restaurant, but can it be used in other situations?

Comment: I'm not sure on this (as I would also be confused between B and D), but it might have to do with the syntax rather than the meaning.  Perhaps B would need to be 合うかどうか**知らない** (not 知らなかった) to be correct.  This would even translate to English correctly:  "You **don't** know whether or not it fits until you actually try it on" vs "You **didn't** know whether or not...".  That's what my gut says, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @istrasci but since the sentence ends with `よかった`, doesn't it force `知らない/だ` to be in the past form?

Comment: @istrasci This is a [compound sentence](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/sentence/compound-sentence.htm), and the rule of relative tense is not relevant because the clause in question is not a subordinate clause.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 「インターネットで注文{ちゅうもん}したセーターは、実際{じっさい}に着{き}てみるまでサイズが_____が、ちょうどよかった。」
>
> A. 合{あ}わなかった
>
> B. 合うかどうか知{し}らなかった
>
> C. 合わないかもしれない
>
> D. 合うか不安{ふあん}だった

First of all, A and C are out of the question as neither one logically fits the context.

From my personal experience with Japanese-learners, I know many of them would think B was correct, but it is not.  **B is "grammatical" if anything, but contextually, that is not where native speakers would use the verb 「知る」 in the first place**.

What is the other verb that means "to know" that you may have been wondering why native speakers use so often?  It is, of course, 「わかる」.  If B had read 「合うかどうか**わからなかった**」 instead of 「合うかどうか**知らなかった**」, it would have been a correct answer as well.

Regarding D, it is correct as is, making it the *only* correct answer among the four choices.

> "不安だ is rather strong, like I'm not gonna be anxious because I'm not sure if my sweater will fit."

It is not necessarily strong used all by itself for us native speakers.  If you added qualifiers such as 「とても」、「大変{たいへん}」, etc, it would certainly be strong.

Finally, 「注文」 is used to request and purchase all kinds of goods and services both online and in real life.  It is not only used in eateries.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I know about 知る and わかる, but I still mix them up from time to time...